# Implementing the From trait for a ParseIntError

Tags: rust, traits

When using the try! macro, it uses the From trait to transform an error into the desired error.

I would like to transform some errors into my own type. This goes great for e.g. io::Error, but I can't get it to work for an error type from core.

```
use std::io;

pub struct ParserError {
    pub message: String,
}

impl From<io::Error> for ParserError {
    fn from(e: io::Error) -> ParserError {
        ParserError{message: format!("Generic IO error: {}", e.description())}
    }
}
```

This works well for doing try! on anything io. But now for parsing:

```
fn parse_string(s: &str) -> Result<u64, ParserError> {
    let i = try!(s.parse::<u64>());
    return Ok(i);
}
```

My error says:

error: the trait `core::convert::From<parser::ParserError>` is not implemented for the type `core::num::ParseIntError

I tried to implement this From:

```
impl From<core::num::ParseIntError> for ParserError {
    fn from(_: core::num::ParseIntError) -> ParserError {
        ParserError{message: "Invalid data type".to_string()}
    }
}
```

But I can't get core imported. How to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The modules from `core` are reexported by `std`. You can fix your error by just replacing `core` by `std` in your code:

```
impl From<std::num::ParseIntError> for ParserError {
    fn from(_: std::num::ParseIntError) -> ParserError {
        ParserError{message: "Invalid data type".to_string()}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a bug filed about this issue, the fact that the compiler complains about internal types is a paper cut: had the compiler complained about `std::num::ParseIntError` then the OP would have implemented the correct solution directly. (And I do know it's probably far from simple)

Comment: @MatthieuM. There are few issues that are at least related, e.g. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23355 . I couldn't find one for this exact problem, but in general this is a known problem.

Comment: Interestingly enough this works on my toy problem, but in my real code I get "error: failed to resolve. Use of undeclared type or module `std::num`" and error: use of undeclared type name `std::num::ParseIntError`

Comment: I actually had tried std in my complete code... Any idea what the problem is when that error pops up?

Comment: @PeterSmit Try using `::std::num::ParseIntError` (note the `::` prefix).

Comment: @fjh Thanks, that did the trick. It seems std is not present in sub-modules

Comment: That's correct, std is imported as a crate and added to the root of the module hierarchy. Just like an `extern crate std;` line at your own crate's root.